# Add HTML Form into JSON Object

Tags: php, html, json, web

I am a Web Noob, but I am using a JSON Feed for a app I am making. I want the JSON to be able to have objects added to it by office people. So how would I use a html form to have objects added to a json file then saved (JSON will be on a server)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hope this would help

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>JSON Object Creation in JavaScript</h2>
<p>
Name: <span id="jname"></span><br /> 
Age: <span id="jage"></span><br /> 
Address: <span id="jstreet"></span><br /> 
Phone: <span id="jphone"></span><br /> 
</p>

<script>
var JSONObject= {
"name":"John Johnson",
"street":"Oslo West 555", 
"age":33,
"phone":"555 1234567"};
document.getElementById("jname").innerHTML=JSONObject.name 
document.getElementById("jage").innerHTML=JSONObject.age 
document.getElementById("jstreet").innerHTML=JSONObject.street 
document.getElementById("jphone").innerHTML=JSONObject.phone 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

you can use either json_decode for decoding values or you can just insert these values into hidden elements and fetch it on your php code on just submit as normal form data

```
$data = json_decode($json_string);
$output = array();
foreach($data as $values){
$output[] = $values->id;
}
```

for more details just follow the link
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Awesome! Just one question how would I add this to a Array of objects and then save on the server?

Comment: you can use either json_decode for decoding values or you can just insert these values into hidden elements and fetch it on your php code on just submit as normal form data                                $data = json_decode($json_string);
$output = array();
foreach($data as $values){
  $output[] = $values->id;
}